# Two multi select checkboxes column inside gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

i have two checkboxes for two columns, so once it click on the select all headerChkbox it should only be selected for all chkStatus and same goes with chkUpdate

but the below code is selecting and unselecting both  when iam going to select any one.but i want to make them independent of each other.means when i select headerChkbox all the checkboxes in that particular column only should be selected or un selected same goes for other

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="CheckBoxTemplateColumn">
    <HeaderStyle Width="50px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkStatus" runat="server" Width="15px" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("isAssignJD")) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="headerChkbox" runat="server" onclick="javascript:SelectAllCheckboxesSpecific(this);" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="CheckBoxTemplate">
    <HeaderStyle Width="50px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkUpdate" runat="server" Width="15px" Checked="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="headerUpdate" runat="server"  onclick="javascript:SelectAllCheckboxesSpecific(this);" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

And Here is my Function

```
function SelectAllCheckboxesSpecific(spanChk) {
    //  Select checkboxes that place in grid
    var IsChecked = spanChk.checked;
    var Chk = spanChk;
    Parent = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvJobPosition');
    var items = Parent.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].id != Chk && items[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (items[i].checked != IsChecked) {
                items[i].click();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Html rendered Code

```
<tr class="rgRow" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvJobPosition_ctl00__0">
    <td style="display:none;">0561fb4f-e410-4d83-a0e5-6d6d68fe3dba</td><td align="left">
                                    <span class="category1" style="display:inline-block;width:15px;"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvJobPosition_ctl00_ctl04_chkStatus" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvJobPosition$ctl00$ctl04$chkStatus" checked="checked" /></span>
                                </td><td align="left">
                                    <span class="category2" style="display:inline-block;width:15px;"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvJobPosition_ctl00_ctl04_chkStatuss" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvJobPosition$ctl00$ctl04$chkStatuss" /></span>
                                </td>
```

Comment: I updated the code with a working example, just don't forget to include the jQuery js file.

Answer (score 0):

This line is your problem:

```
var items = Parent.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

You are selecting *all* checkboxes on the page.  Why not use jQuery? It is much easier:

Give all checkboxes in category 1, class="category1" and give class="category2" for all checkboxes in category 2.

Then give class="setAll1" and class="setAll2" for the header checkboxes. Then write:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.setAll1').click(function(){
        if($('.setAll1').is(':checked'))
            $('.category1').prop('checked',true);
        else 
            $('.category1').prop('checked',false);
    });
    $('.setAll2').click(function(){
        if($('.setAll2').is(':checked'))
            $('.category2').prop('checked',true);
        else
            $('.category2').prop('checked',false);
    });
});
```

And for html:

```
<body>
    <input type=checkbox class="setAll1"/>
    <input type=checkbox class="category1"/><input type=checkbox class="category1"/><input type=checkbox class="category1"/>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <input type=checkbox class="setAll2"/>
    <input type=checkbox class="category2"/><input type=checkbox class="category2"/><input type=checkbox class="category2"/>
</body>
```

There are many ways to do this in jQuery, but this way was the first that came to my head.

Comment: Can You show me some sample code iam new to Jquery,Javascript

Comment: I think asp: checkbox does not render as checkbox as html checkbox. It creates a span and the class is assigned to the span, not to the checkbox. Probably you have to use `$('.setAll1 input:checkbox')` instead of `$('.setAll1')`. Or use html checkbox.

Comment: I tested and fixed the code, but it uses regular checkboxes, as shown.

Comment: This code exactly, works on my machine. Show us what you have so far. Do you get any errors in JS console? Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/d8vuK/

Comment: Dude i think afzalulh is right perhaps  iam using asp.net checkbox instead of html that is why its not working although  i have also tryed $('.setAll1 input:checkbox') instead of $('.setAll1')

Comment: It would really help if you show the Html code that is rendered from your code, especially where the checkboxes are.

Comment: @Ameer Ali - As this answer needs some minor modifications, I don't feel like posting another answer. My Suggestion is, you have to replace all `$('.AspCheckBoxClass')` with `$('.AspCheckBox input:checkbox')`. You can debug in firebug and see if your code is getting correct element.